# Why is the animation speeding up after being resumed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, tkinter

I'm working on an animation of a simple pendulum in tkinter. I've bound the <kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>r</kbd> to the window to `stop` and `resume` the animation.  But I've noticed a weird quirk I can't explain: if I press <kbd>r</kbd> when the pendulum is not stopped, it speeds up.  I can't figure out why it's happening.  Can anyone explain what is happening and how to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
from math import sqrt, cos, sin, radians
from tkinter import *

class SimplePendulum:
    def __init__(self):
        # Create a window
        win = Tk()
        win.title('Pendulum')

        # Create a canvas
        self.w, self.h = 250, 300
        self.canvas = Canvas(win, width=self.w, height=self.h, bg='white')
        self.canvas.pack()

        # Bind keys to the window
        win.bind('s', self.stop)
        win.bind('S', self.stop)
        win.bind('r', self.resume)
        win.bind('R', self.resume)

        # Pendulum constants
        self.g = 1
        self.L = 4*self.h/5
        self.theta_i = radians(20)

        # Initialize time t to 0
        self.t = 0

        # Start animation
        self.isStopped = False
        self.speed = 1/50           # initial frequency of oscillation
        self.animate()

        # Start the event loop
        win.mainloop()

    def drawPendulum(self):
        # Angle of the pendulum (from the vertial) at time t
        theta = self.theta_i * cos(sqrt(self.g/self.L) * self.t)
        # The two ends of the cord
        x_i, y_i = self.w/2, self.h/10
        x_f, y_f = x_i + self.L*sin(theta), y_i + self.L*cos(theta)
        # Draw the cord and bob of the pendulum
        self.canvas.create_line(x_i, y_i, x_f, y_f, tags='cord')
        rad = min(self.w, self.h)/20
        self.canvas.create_oval(x_f - rad, y_f - rad,
                                x_f + rad, y_f + rad, fill='red', tags='bob')

    def animate(self):
        if not self.isStopped:
            self.canvas.delete(ALL)
            self.drawPendulum()
            self.t += 2
            self.canvas.after(int(1/self.speed), self.animate)

    def stop(self, event):
        self.isStopped = True

    def resume(self, event):
        self.isStopped = False
        self.animate()

SimplePendulum()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace `resume` to:

```
def resume(self, event):
    if self.isStopped:
        self.isStopped = False
        self.animate()
```

When the `resume` is run w/o if `self.isStopped` flag check, it runs a new `animate` which has its own recursion of calling itself, thus it calls linearly increasing `animate` methods each time `resume` is called w/o the flag.

Comment: Oh.  I see.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Not really related to your question, but your animation would be smoother if you updated the elements on the canvas rather than clearing the entire canvas and redrawing from scratch:

```
from math import sqrt, cos, sin, radians
from tkinter import *

class SimplePendulum:
    def __init__(self):
        # Create a window
        win = Tk()
        win.title('Pendulum')

        # Create a canvas
        self.w, self.h = 250, 300
        self.canvas = Canvas(win, width=self.w, height=self.h, bg='white')
        self.canvas.pack()

        # Bind keys to the window
        win.bind('s', self.stop)
        win.bind('S', self.stop)
        win.bind('r', self.resume)
        win.bind('R', self.resume)

        # Pendulum constants
        self.g = 1
        self.L = 4*self.h/5
        self.theta_i = radians(20)

        # Initialize time t to 0
        self.t = 0
        cord, bob = self.calcPendulum()
        self.cord = self.canvas.create_line(*cord, tags='cord')
        self.bob = self.canvas.create_oval(*bob, fill='red', tags='bob')

        # Start animation
        self.isStopped = False
        self.speed = 1/50           # initial frequency of oscillation
        self.animate()

        # Start the event loop
        win.mainloop()

    def calcPendulum(self):
        # Angle of the pendulum (from the vertial) at time t
        theta = self.theta_i * cos(sqrt(self.g/self.L) * self.t)
        # The two ends of the cord
        x_i, y_i = self.w/2, self.h/10
        x_f, y_f = x_i + self.L*sin(theta), y_i + self.L*cos(theta)
        rad = min(self.w, self.h)/20
        cord_pos = x_i, y_i, x_f, y_f
        bob_pos = x_f - rad, y_f - rad, x_f + rad, y_f + rad
        return cord_pos, bob_pos

    def animate(self):
        if not self.isStopped:
            cord, bob = self.calcPendulum()
            self.canvas.coords(self.cord, *cord)
            self.canvas.coords(self.bob, *bob)
            self.t += 2
            self.canvas.after(int(1/self.speed), self.animate)

    def stop(self, event):
        self.isStopped = True

    def resume(self, event):
        self.isStopped = False
        self.animate()

SimplePendulum()
```

Also, there is no point to having a class here. I suspect you did that because you saw or were told that everything in GUIs needs a class. But the key to that is that it needs to be a subclass of a GUI widget. For instance, you could have made the SimplePendulum class a type of Canvas:

```
from math import sqrt, cos, sin, radians
from tkinter import *

class SimplePendulum(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, bg='white', **kwargs)

        # Bind keys to the window
        master.bind('s', self.stop)
        master.bind('S', self.stop)
        master.bind('r', self.resume)
        master.bind('R', self.resume)

        # Pendulum constants
        self.g = 1
        self.theta_i = radians(20)

        # Initialize time t to 0
        self.t = 0
        cord, bob = self.calcPendulum()
        self.cord = self.create_line(*cord, tags='cord')
        self.bob = self.create_oval(*bob, fill='red', tags='bob')

        # Start animation
        self.timer = ''
        self.speed = 1/50           # initial frequency of oscillation
        self.animate()

    def calcPendulum(self):
        # Angle of the pendulum (from the vertial) at time t
        L = 4*self.winfo_height()/5
        theta = self.theta_i * cos(sqrt(self.g/L) * self.t)
        # The two ends of the cord
        x_i, y_i = self.winfo_width()/2, self.winfo_height()/10
        x_f, y_f = x_i + L*sin(theta), y_i + L*cos(theta)
        rad = min(self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height())/20
        cord_pos = x_i, y_i, x_f, y_f
        bob_pos = x_f - rad, y_f - rad, x_f + rad, y_f + rad
        return cord_pos, bob_pos

    def animate(self):
        cord, bob = self.calcPendulum()
        self.coords(self.cord, *cord)
        self.coords(self.bob, *bob)
        self.t += 2
        self.timer = self.after(int(1/self.speed), self.animate)

    def stop(self, event=None):
        self.after_cancel(self.timer)

    def resume(self, event=None):
        self.stop() # in case it's currently running, stop it
        self.animate()

def main():
    # Create a window
    win = Tk()
    win.title('Pendulum')
    part = SimplePendulum(win, width=200, height=300)
    part.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    win.mainloop() # Start the event loop

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now you can use your new widget in a little demo program like I did or pack it into any bigger program. Or use it multiple times.

I also moved a couple other things around, like putting the length calculation in the timed step so that you can resize the window and the pendulum resizes as well. Your math makes this a lot of fun since it nicely demonstrates the relation between pendulum length and frequency. Hmm now that we have it in a neat widget we can easily demo that by putting a short one and a tall one on the screen together:

```
def main():
    # Create a window
    win = Tk()
    win.title('Pendulum')
    part = SimplePendulum(win, width=200, height=100)
    part.pack(side=LEFT)
    part = SimplePendulum(win, width=400, height=600)
    part.pack(side=LEFT)
    win.mainloop() # Start the event loop
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the improvements!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `after_cancel` to cancel the queue for the animation. Not sure if there is an advantage to this though:

```
from math import sqrt, cos, sin, radians
from tkinter import *

class SimplePendulum:
    def __init__(self):
        # Create a window
        win = Tk()
        win.title('Pendulum')

        # Create a canvas
        self.w, self.h = 250, 300
        self.canvas = Canvas(win, width=self.w, height=self.h, bg='white')
        self.canvas.pack()

        # Bind keys to the window
        win.bind('s', self.stop)
        win.bind('S', self.stop)
        win.bind('r', self.resume)
        win.bind('R', self.resume)

        # Pendulum constants
        self.g = 1
        self.L = 4*self.h/5
        self.theta_i = radians(20)

        # Initialize time t to 0
        self.t = 0
        self._queue = False

        # Start animation
        self.isStopped = False
        self.speed = 1/50           # initial frequency of oscillation
        self.animate()

        # Start the event loop
        win.mainloop()

    def drawPendulum(self):
        # Angle of the pendulum (from the vertial) at time t
        theta = self.theta_i * cos(sqrt(self.g/self.L) * self.t)
        # The two ends of the cord
        x_i, y_i = self.w/2, self.h/10
        x_f, y_f = x_i + self.L*sin(theta), y_i + self.L*cos(theta)
        # Draw the cord and bob of the pendulum
        self.canvas.create_line(x_i, y_i, x_f, y_f, tags='cord')
        rad = min(self.w, self.h)/20
        self.canvas.create_oval(x_f - rad, y_f - rad,
                                x_f + rad, y_f + rad, fill='red', tags='bob')

    def animate(self):
        self.canvas.delete(ALL)
        self.drawPendulum()
        self.t += 2
        self._queue = self.canvas.after(int(1/self.speed), self.animate)

    def stop(self, event):
        if self._queue:
            self.canvas.after_cancel(self._queue)
            self._queue = False

    def resume(self, event):
        if not self._queue:
            self.animate()

SimplePendulum()
```